# AdonisJS single route won't open

Tags: node.js, adonis.js, edgejs

I've made this project with AdonisJS, this is PlaceController file content:

```
async create({
    view
  }) {
    return view.render('places.new')
  }
```

and this is view file path: `views/places/new.edge` which is a simple static HTML file.

and the routes.js file content:

```
Route.get('admin/places/new', 'PlaceController.create')
```

when I enter the URL in browser, the URL just disappears.the problem solves by removing `admin` from route. Is there a bug in this framework or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So problem solved. another Route caused this problem.
it was

```
Route.get('admin/places/:id', 'PlaceController.edit').middleware(['admin'])
Route.get('admin/places/new/', 'PlaceController.create').middleware(['admin'])
```

changed the order to:

```
Route.get('admin/places/new/', 'PlaceController.create').middleware(['admin'])
Route.get('admin/places/:id', 'PlaceController.edit').middleware(['admin'])
```

now it works.